# oracle sqlplus not returning values for loop with select

Tags: oracle, cursor, sqlplus

I have created a for in loop with a select in a similar way:

```
for i in (select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = '')
   strinvar := i.column_name
```

This code when executed in plsql developer will return:
column1
column2
etc

When i tried to execute this in sqlplus i didn't get any result.. Also i tried to do this in sqlplus and printing the results in file like:

```
 for i in (select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = '')
       strinvar := i.column_name
utl_file.put_line(Filehandle, strinvar);
```

but it didn't printed anything. Am i missing something?
Finally another question has to do with getting the value inside the select statement from a variable like:

```
declare 
tab_name varchar2(100) := 'Test';

Begin
 for i in (select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = tab_name )
           strinvar := i.column_name
    utl_file.put_line(Filehandle, strinvar);
```

Can i have something like this or should i create a cursor for the table names and fetch the names from the cursor?

Can you please advice me.
Best Regards
George Georgiou

Comment: Aside from your code not being valid - missing `loop` and `end loop`, missing semicolons etc., and you seem to be looking for a table with a `null` name - and assuming you are actually running the same (valid) code in both clients, are you connected as the same user, or at least as two users who can access the table you're getting the columns for?

Comment: The code i wrote above is just pseudocode it is not sth that will compile because i am not at work to see the actual code. Also on the query i remember i tried with select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = ''and owner = user and that also didn't make any difference. My question has to do whether i can execute a for in stmt in sqlplus and also if i can have the table name as variable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a spool in conjunction with your select statements inside the script, and are you writing this in Powershell/bat/SQL or just wanting to run manually on demand?  Also, if you are trying to get column-names from a specific table to pass as a variable you may want to spool the output into an array so that you will be able to handle the output as variables.